# How to share image to facebook from fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, share, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm using Facebook SDK and I want to know how to use share in fragment

```
public class FullScreenImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

private Activity _activity;
private ArrayList<String> _imagePaths;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
public CallbackManager callbackManager;
public LoginManager loginManager;
// constructor
public FullScreenImageAdapter(Activity activity,
        ArrayList<String> imagePaths) {
    this._activity = activity;
    this._imagePaths = imagePaths;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this._imagePaths.size();
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == ((RelativeLayout) object);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    TouchImageView imgDisplay;
    Button btnClose;



    inflater = (LayoutInflater) _activity
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View viewLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.full_photo, container,
            false);

    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(_activity.getApplicationContext());
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    List<String> permissionNeeds = Arrays.asList("publish_actions");
    //this loginManager helps you eliminate adding a LoginButton to your UI
    LoginManager manager = LoginManager.getInstance();
    manager.logInWithPublishPermissions(this, permissionNeeds);*// It Problem
```

It Problem  manager.logInWithPublishPermissions(this, permissionNeeds) cannot resolve method

And problem super.onActivityResult it cannot reslove

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

}
```

Plese help me   or solve solution here Sorry I'm Weak  English Language

Comment: Do    `manager.logInWithPublishPermissions(_activity, permissionNeeds);`

Comment: and  onActivityResult is problem

Comment: Have you solve it yet?